# Key error on database name

Tags: bash, postgresql

I am trying to run the dedupe library and this example on Ubuntu Bash command.

https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe-examples/tree/master/pgsql_big_dedupe_example

Basically, I created a database called campfin as you can see when I list the database names, it does exist.

```
postgres=# \l
                               List of databases
   Name    |    Owner    | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges
-----------+-------------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 campfin   | simon       | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
 dbname    | owning_user | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
 postgres  | postgres    | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
 template0 | postgres    | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |             |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres    | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |             |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)

postgres=# \c campfin
You are now connected to database "campfin" as user "postgres".
campfin=# sudo netstat -plunt |grep postmaster
campfin-#  \conninfo
You are connected to database "campfin" as user "postgres" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5433".
campfin-#
```

When i run my python code :

```
python3 pgsql_big_dedupe_example_init_db.py
```

or

```
sudo python3 pgsql_big_dedupe_example_init_db.py
```

This is the part of mode to connect to the database.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database=db_conf['campfin'],
                        user=db_conf['111'],
                        password=db_conf['111'],
                        host=db_conf['localhost'],
                        port=db_conf['5433'])
```

In returns me that the database campfin does not exist:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pgsql_big_dedupe_example_init_db.py", line 75, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=db_conf['campfin'],
KeyError: 'campfin'
```

what I am doing wrong here? Is the issue related to " via socket in "/var/run/postgresql"? Which is not my localhost?

When I run:

```
/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/virtualenv/dedupe/dedupe-examples/pgsql_big_dedupe_example$ service postgresql status
```

in returns: 10/main (port 5433): online

Answer (score 0):

`db_conf['NAME']` is not meant to change to `db_conf['campfin']`. The **key** is `NAME`, the **value** of it will be `campfin` !

In the command-line, run

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://111:111@localhost/campfin
```

Then run `python3 pgsql_big_dedupe_example_init_db.py` with the original code ...

```
con = psycopg2.connect(database=db_conf['NAME'],
                   user=db_conf['USER'],
                   password=db_conf['PASSWORD'],
                   host=db_conf['HOST'],
                   cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
```